# Why are rotation numbers not homomorphic?

Tags: dynamical-systems, rotations, ergodic-theory, big-picture, arithmetic-dynamics

If $f,g$ are degree-1 monotone maps of the circle, **why** do we generally have $\rho(f\circ g)\neq\rho(f)+\rho(g)$?

I mean, you might say that we have no right to expect an equality. After all, it's not hard to come up with counterexamples. For example, if $f$ is the piecewise-affine map that interpolates $[0,\frac13]\mapsto[0,\frac23]$ and $[\frac13, 1]\mapsto[\frac23,1]$, then $\rho(f)=0$, yet $\rho(f+\frac13)=\frac12$, rather than $\frac13$. But I still feel like there ought to be something deeper; some satisfying, big-picture reason why a homomorphism identity fails.

Is the "real" reason that $f$ and $g$ tend to disrupt each others' invariant measures? If so, is there a lurking analogy with number theory, where adding $a+b$ tends to disrupt the prime factorizations of $a$ and $b$?

What's the smart way to think about this?

Google tells me that something like my question is addressed in "Structure Theorems for Groups of Homeomorphisms of the Circle" at https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.0218, but I'll be honest, that's too much to digest.

(For what it's worth, this question is motivated by reading chapter 1 of Zakeri's *Rotation Sets and Complex Dynamics*, and wondering if it's unfair that we have to work so hard to nail down lemmas that ought to be free, if only these things could behave a little better.)

---

Edit: For completeness, here's the relevant part of the paper I mentioned.

> **Lemma 1.8** (Beklaryan and Margulis, [3, 21]). *Let $G \leq \mathrm{Homeo}_+(S^1)$. Then the following alternative holds:*
>
> 1. *$G$ has a non-abelian free subgroup, or*
> 2. *the map $\mathrm{Rot} : G \to (\mathbb R/\mathbb Z, +)$ is a group homomorphism.*
>
> The heart of the proof of Lemma 1.8 is contained in the following lemma, which itself is proven using only on classical results (Poincare’s Lemma and the Ping-pong Lemma)...

I'm not sure that this lemma conveys the intuition that I'm looking for. It does tell us a lot about what the obstructions to a homomorphism look like. But I still feel like I'm missing a "why".

Comment: Have you found a "why" for your actual counterexample? I would think that would be a good place to start.

Comment: @LeeMosher Hmm. Rotation by $\frac13$ has a bunch of period-3 cycles, of which the nicest to write down is the orbit of $0$, namely $0\mapsto\frac13\mapsto\frac23\mapsto0$. Then when we compose (in either order) that rotation with $f$, which maps $0\mapsto0$ and $\frac13\mapsto\frac23$, we create a "short-cut" across that period-3 cycle, leaving a period-2 cycle. So to try and translate this to a "why": It's **possible** for $f$ to act on another map's cycles by "skipping around" in a way that is potentially independent from $f$'s own time-average behavior. Does that sound right?

Comment: I think that's a nice way of putting it.